# I have installed correctly opencv_contrib but qt creator doesn't find xfeatures2d directory

Tags: opencv, surf, opencv-contrib

I am using OpenCV with C++ on Ubuntu 16.01 I have to use SURF.

I have already installed opencv_contrib correctly (i followed this [link](https://github.com/roboticslab-uc3m/installation-guides/blob/master/install-opencv.md)) but when i try to write the path:

```
#include "xfeatures2d/xfeatures2d.hpp
```

in my .hpp program I found this error:

```
#include "xfeatures2d/xfeatures2d.hpp : No such file or directory
```

Also i tried to put all the directory but it doesn't work either.

I'm not an expert in opencv so i don't know if I have to change any CmakeList or something.

has anybody any ideas?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you don't need opencv_contribs for SURF asf Opencv itself has its own implementation. Generally, if you can avoid contribs, just do so since it relies on a lot of obsolete code and is not very well tested. As for your error,  I think it would be difficult to help you if you don't show the relevant cmake and compilation flags etc.

Comment: @ash I think that i need the library "xfeatures2d" to use SURF because qt and visual studio (i also tried in windows) dont recognise the command "SurfFeatureDetector" when i triy to compile the program. Moreover, there is too many things in the two foulders and i dont know which archives i need to put here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include path:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C://opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules/xfeatures2d/include"
```

in your .pro file.